# How to compare a 7-month forward-looking data crossing 2022 and 2023 with 2019?

Tags: teradata, teradata-sql-assistant, teradatasql

I have below the code:

```
SELECT T.postdate_debug AS POSTDATE,
(CAST(T.DEPART_DATE AS DATE FORMAT 'MM') (char(2))) AS "Month",
SUM(CASE WHEN T.dpt_date_yr_debug IN ('2019') THEN T.tot_REV ELSE 0 END) AS PY_REVENUE_THIS_WEEK,
SUM(CASE WHEN T.dpt_date_yr_debug IN (EXTRACT(YEAR FROM CURRENT_DATE)-1, EXTRACT(YEAR FROM CURRENT_DATE)) AND T.postdate_debug = CURRENT_DATE - TD_DAY_OF_WEEK(CURRENT_DATE)+1 THEN T.tot_REV ELSE 0 END) AS CY_REVENUE_THIS_WEEK,
SUM(CASE WHEN T.dpt_date_yr_debug IN (EXTRACT(YEAR FROM CURRENT_DATE)-1, EXTRACT(YEAR FROM CURRENT_DATE)) AND T.postdate_debug = CURRENT_DATE - TD_DAY_OF_WEEK(CURRENT_DATE)-6 THEN T.tot_REV ELSE 0 END) AS CY_REVENUE_LAST_WEEK,
SUM(CASE WHEN T.dpt_date_yr_debug IN (EXTRACT(YEAR FROM CURRENT_DATE)-1, EXTRACT(YEAR FROM CURRENT_DATE)) AND T.postdate_debug = CURRENT_DATE - TD_DAY_OF_WEEK(CURRENT_DATE)-13 THEN T.tot_REV ELSE 0 END) AS CY_REVENUE_TWO_WEEKS

FROM T
WHERE
(
(
(T.DEPART_DATE BETWEEN ADD_MONTHS(CURRENT_DATE - EXTRACT(DAY FROM CURRENT_DATE)+1, 0) AND ADD_MONTHS(CURRENT_DATE - EXTRACT(DAY FROM CURRENT_DATE)+1, +7) -1)
AND (T.postdate_debug=CURRENT_DATE - TD_DAY_OF_WEEK(CURRENT_DATE)+1 OR T.postdate_debug=CURRENT_DATE - TD_DAY_OF_WEEK(CURRENT_DATE)-6  OR T.postdate_debug=CURRENT_DATE - TD_DAY_OF_WEEK(CURRENT_DATE)-13)
)

OR

(
(T.DEPART_DATE BETWEEN ADD_MONTHS(CURRENT_DATE - EXTRACT(DAY FROM CURRENT_DATE)+1, -36) AND ADD_MONTHS(CURRENT_DATE - EXTRACT(DAY FROM CURRENT_DATE)+1, +7-36) -1)
AND T.postdate_debug=CURRENT_DATE - TD_DAY_OF_WEEK(CURRENT_DATE)-1095
)
)
```

And the outcome is:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0tB1j.png)

My question is: when moving to next month, the 7-month forward-looking will be 7,8,9,10,11,12,1, and I would like the month of 1 data still compare with 2019-1. Any suggestion how to achieve this?

Comment: Is it safe to assume that T is already aggregated so that POSTDATE already has 1 row for every week, no duplicates and also none missing?

Comment: @Josh no T is not aggregated. POSTDATE are duplicates.